# Ext.Direct Form Integration

Tags: extjs

I am using Ext.direct.RemotingProvider . At the server side I make some validation checks. The Respond is send back in JSON format.

If i find any errors when making validation checks, the field success = false, and errors will contain the error.

I am trying to figure out, how do i reflect errors i found in the server side in the form (client side).

In the link below there is an example of what i want to achieve. When the client press on "submit" an error message will occur in the form, how does it work ?

[Example](http://dev.sencha.com/deploy/dev/examples/direct/direct-form.php)

In the code i post in the bottom the following happens:
in the browser there are 2 fields (Name,Email) and 2 buttons.
the fields are irrelevant for now. they are used as dummies.

Each time the user press on "Add" button, a new action is added into callBuffer of Ext.direct.RemotingProvider
When the user press on "Apply" button, all the actions are being sent to the router (MVC model) and from there to a specific controller. (the function sfw.Direct.getProvider('sfwProvider').combineAndSend() is triggered).

As for now, i intentionally fails the respond and create an error field, just like the example link i added in the beginning of the Thread.
i put in the errors field {email="Already exists"}.
but i see not effect in the form..

what am i doing wrong ?

Code:

```
appWiki.main_panel = new Ext.FormPanel({
        renderTo: 'extjs_panels_container'
        , id: 'appWiki_main_panel'
        , name: 'appWiki_main_panel'
        , defaultType: 'textfield'

        , items: [
            { 
            fieldLabel: 'Name',
            name: 'name'
            }
            ,{
            fieldLabel: 'Email',
            msgTarget: 'side',
            name: 'email'
        }]

        ,buttons:[
        {xtype: 'sfw.Button'
        , text: 'Add'
        , handler: function(){sfw.rule.store.api.readByRowId({data: {_ROWID_: 1}});}
        }
        ,{text: 'Submit'
        , handler: function(){
            appWiki.main_panel.getForm().submit({
            });
        }       
        }]

    ,api: {
        // The server-side must mark the submit handler as a 'formHandler'
        submit: sumbitAllRequests
    }   
    , load: function()
    {

        setTimeout("hide_loading_mask()",2000);
    }

    });
```

Answer (score 0):

In the JSON response you need the following structure

```
{ "result" : { "success": false, "errors": { "name of field" : "validation message" } }
```

Where `"name of field"` is the `name` config option in your field, and `"validation message"` is the message you want to display to the user.

When you send a response like that ExtJS will take care of the rest.

EDIT: You may also need to enable QuickTips:

`Ext.QuickTips.init();`

Add that line before you declare your form

EDIT 2: Also, make sure you're using the `submit()` method found on the `BasicForm`:

```
    buttons:[{
        text: 'Submit',
        handler: function(){
            basicInfo.getForm().submit({
                params: {
                    foo: 'bar',
                    uid: 34
                }
            });
        }
    }],
```

Comment: hi Jaitsu, that is what i am returning from the server, but no effect on the form --> {"type":"rpc","status":true,"tid":5,"result":{"success":false,"errors":{"email":"already taken"}}}

Comment: Hi, i added Ext.QuickTips.init(); at the beginning (before creating the formPanel), but still not working... any more ideas of what i might be missing ?

Comment: okay, from looking at the example I think you need to use a native `submit()` method to submit your form data, otherwise ExtJS will not apply the validation messages... I've added the code to my answer

Comment: okay, i added the submit() method. and it sends that data to the server. but still no effect on the form  (i've edited the post)

Comment: what does it mean: " The server-side must mark the submit handler as a 'formHandler'" ?  this comment is from the code in the api barracks